# Cocoa Touch Framework: Structs and Protocols missing in .framework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm creating a cocoa touch framework in Swift, but unfortunately stuff that's specific to Swift is missing, like structs and protocols.

Is there no possibility at all to include these? Or am I missing something?

Classes are working fine, but my structs are missing as well as my protocol declarations...

**EDIT**:

Is it necessary to have the files in "Copy Bundle Sources" as well? I just found in a newly created cocoa touch framework that most of the files are not added by default there...

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

please have a look at https://github.com/haemi/SwiftFramework

when I build it and include the framework into an iOS project, I only have access to `MyStruct.something()`, not `AnotherFile.something()` although that's public as well...

Comment: Sure they are possible! So I guess you are missing something. Show us some code and we'll get you working....

Comment: @dfd please see my edit, thanks!

Comment: Added an answer. If it's close but not complete, let me know.

Comment: @dfd it didn't help unfortunately, but I made another edit with code

Comment: Ok. I deleted my answer - it didn't help. I added your framework to a small project and see the issue. I have a fix, but I don't know why your code didn't work. Like you, I was able to pull `MyStruct` into my project and access `something()`. I also could do the same with `AndYetAnotherFile`. But **only** when I changed `struct AnotherFile` to `struct YetAnotherFile` did things work. Before that, I had the same issue - even when I removed `static`. It's behaving like it doesn't like `AnotherFile` for a structure name, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: that's more than strange - renaming helped in my case as well... This doesn't make sense AT ALL.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to go from there. Xcode issue? Swift issue? (BTW, I'm using code 9 and Swift 4.) That's the main reason I both deleted my answer (it didn't help) and kept the comments short. Hey, I guessed I still kinda helped. No clue as to why though. Like you, I'm filing this weirdness for future reference. ONE THOUGHT: While I sure won't take the time for this, maybe starting from scratch and naming things less generically (and then slowly doing things generically) will reveal the real issue.

Comment: you DID help, that's for sure - thanks!